# How does the Java program load if I call a static method in another static method

Tags: java

I understand that static method will load first when a class is accessed at the first time. I wonder how does the java knows which static method to be loaded first if one static method call another static one. For example:

```
class Test{
    public static void a(){
        b();
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
    public static void b(){
        System.out.println("World");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        a();
    }
}
```

In the above code, a() can be called only if b() is properly bound. How does the java knows that it should bind b() first?

Comment: When calling a static method, the class is initialized. The method isn't "loaded". There is no order to "loading" methods. When your program starts, the static method `main` is called, which means the `Test` class is loaded. Neither `a` nor `b` are ever loaded, except inasmuch as `Test` is loaded.

Comment: what do you understando for: ***initialize b()*** ???or initializr a method??

Comment: To say initialize, I mean binding, sorry.

Comment: _a() can be called only if b() has been called_: - but you have called `a()` before calling `b()`

Comment: Whenever a class is referenced defualt class loader finds the class is the class path and loads it into runtime pool(permgen). This is case for your and jdk classes. Classes loaded by the ClassLoader is stored internally in the ClassLoader instance

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I guess I understand where is my problem thanks to the comments.

The static method will be early bound(or static bound) by the compilation, however the binding process will only fix the type of the variables and expressions instead of checking the revoked methods inside the static one. For my problem, the compiler will still early bind the two methods a() and b(), but a() will not call b() until run time, because it considers that the b() inside a() may be a dynamic bound method.

Above is just my guess. If I have further mistakes in my answer, welcome any correction.